# Hibernate 4 not sorting

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-4.x

I have a SortedSet within an entity. But when I try to fetch it doesn't sort. I tried to use hibernate or jpa, both not working. Any reason? (My set entity has implemented comparable too)

```
    private SortedSet<News> news = new TreeSet<News>();

    public void setNews(SortedSet<News> news) {
    this.news = news;
}

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "NEWSGROUP_NEWS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "NEWSGROUP_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "NEWS_ID"))
    @OrderBy("title")
    @Sort(type=SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator=NewsComparator.class)
    public SortedSet<News> getNews() {
        return this.news;
    }

public static class NewsComparator implements Comparator<News>
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(News news1, News news2) {
            return news1.getTitle().compareTo(news2.getTitle());

        }

    }
```

My Dao

```
NewsGroup newsGroup = (NewsGroup)this.hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(NewsGroup.class, id);
```

I have also printed the sql (with show_sql on) but it doesn't show order by at all.
Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show the definition of the news field and the setter method

Comment: A SortedSet is sorted with a comparator, using Java, in memory.It's not surprising you don't see any `order by` in the generated SQL.

Comment: Try removing @Sort annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMelnik is right, by removing the @Sort, it worked